# How to reduce Seq of functions that return Either with short circuit behavior?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

Take the following example ([adapted from the cats Either documentation](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/either.html#example-usage-round-1)).

Three validation functions are being applied in sequence each returning an Either. If the application of any of the functions fails a Left value is returned.

```
object Validators {
  def isBiggerThan5(i: Int): Either[Exception, Int] =
    if (i > 5) Either.right(i)
    else Either.left(new NumberFormatException(s"${i} is smaller than 5."))

  def isSmallerThan20(i: Int): Either[Exception, Int] =
    if (i < 20) Either.right(i)
    else Either.left(new NumberFormatException(s"${i} is bigger than 20."))

  def isEven(i: Int): Either[Exception, Int] =
    if (i % 2 == 0) Either.right(i)
    else Either.left(new NumberFormatException(s"${i} is not an even number."))
}
```

```
import Validators._

def magic(i: Int): Either[Exception, Int] =
  isBiggerThan5(i).flatMap(isSmallerThan20).flatMap(isEven)
```

Now imagine the three validation functions are passed as arguments:

```
type Ops = Int => Either[Exception, Int]

def magic(ops: Seq[Ops])(s: String): Either[Exception, String] =
  ??? // How to apply ops in sequence with short circuit behavior?

println(magic(Seq(isBiggerThan5, isSmallerThan20, isEven)))
```

How can we evaluate the `Seq[Ops]` one after another with short circuit behavior? I have played around with `Seq.foldLeft` or `Seq.reduce` but could not quite figure it out.

I am not interested in error accumulation. It should simply fail on the first validator that returns a Left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foldLeftM` should work.

```
import cats.syntax.all._
def verify(i: Int, ops: Vector[Ops]): Either[Exception, Int] =
  ops.foldLeftM(i)((i, o) => o(i))
```

Comment: Thank you @MatthisBerndt this is exactly what I was looking for. One small note regarding the implementation: Because `ops` is of type `Seq` I had to call `toList` first to be able to call `foldLeftM`.

Comment: Note to myself: You can either write `ops.toList.foldM(i)((i, o) => o(i))` or `Foldable[List].foldLeftM(ops.toList, i)((i, o) => o(i))`. `ops.toList.foldLeftM(i)((i, o) => o(i))` does not work because the cats implicit List instance only provides `foldM`. However, `foldLeftM` is and alias of `foldM`.

Comment: @Tobi **cats** doesn't provide instances for `Seq` and other non-concrete collections of the hierarchy; mostly because they are not safe to be used.

Answer (score 1):

I agree the best solution is to use `foldLeftM`
However, just for sake of completeness if you want a more *vanilla* solution, this is a perfect use case for `List` and tail-recursion.

```scala
type Ops[A] = A => Either[Exception, A]

def magic[A](initial: A)(ops: List[Ops[A]): Either[Exception, A] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[Ops[A]], current: A): Either[Exception, A] =
    remaining match {
      case step :: tail =>
        step(current) match {
          case Right(next) =>
            loop(remaining = tail, current = next)

          case left @ Left(_) =>
            left
        }

      case Nil =>
        Right(current)
    }

  loop(remaining = ops, current = initial)
}
```

*(after looking at all this boilerplate is when you start to appreciate **cats**)*

Comment: Well if `foldLeftM` didn't exist, then using `foldLeft` wouldn't be much longer: `ops.foldLeft[Either[Exception, Int]](Right(i))((i, o) => i.flatMap(o))`. So there isn't really a reason to write a recursive function.

Comment: @MatthiasBerndtt yeah, the recursion is to stop early, is not needed because `flatMap` would short-circuit, but `foldLeftM` would also stop early.